# Подсчет кол-ва в запросе с group by

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
| id | articul | amount |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  1 | 555-012 |      5 |
|  2 | 555-013 |      6 |
|  3 | 555-013 |      7 |
|  4 | 555-014 |      8 |
|  5 | 555-015 |      9 |
|  6 | 555-016 |      3 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++

//запрос
SELECT `id`,`articul`,`amount` FROM `tovar` GROUP BY `articul`
```

Собственно таблица, запрос... охота узнать сколько какого артикула по кол-ву (поле amount). GROUP BY без которого не могу (нужно в том запросе) - ест-но мешает нормально посчитать кол-во. Подскажите, возможно ли запросом на выходе получить такое:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
| id | articul | amount |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
|  1 | 555-012 |      5 |
|  2 | 555-013 |     13 |
|  4 | 555-014 |      8 |
|  5 | 555-015 |      9 |
|  6 | 555-016 |      3 |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`,`articul`,SUM(`amount`) `am`  FROM `tovar` GROUP BY `articul`;
```

Так пробовали?

Comment: Вау.. нет, но способ суперский! я то думал опять двойной запрос буду изучать. Спасибо!

Comment: @mixalef - тогда вам стоит почитать про [агрегирующие функции][1] в MySQL 
[1]: http://www.sql.ru/docs/sql/u_sql/ch6.shtml